# Next-Previous buttons in SearchView ActionBarSherlock Android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock in my app. I've added a search action in action bar, using SearchView widget in collapse mode. All is working fine but I need add the action buttons: "Next" and "Previous" together the search EditText to navigate between the finding words.
The Search is using in WebView, as a search in web page.

How I can to add this buttons in expanded search button (when you clicking collapse button and expand and shows the edit text).

If is not possible, how I can to do some similar?